# Agg len counts null values in dataframe as one

Tags: python, pandas, count

I apologize since this might be a possible duplicate, I want to calculate the `length` of each instance, and every one of the values is always `,` separated. The issue is: even empty values in my dataframe are counted as `1`, which is wrong.

This is my code essentially,

```
servers.loc[:, 'Servers_added'] = servers['servers.added'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: len(x.split(',')) if x.strip() else 0)
```

I tried using simple `map` and `agg` to calculate the length. but keep running into the same issue. I want the null values to be 0 as it affects my analysis increasing the bias towards 1. I run into the same issue with some of my other columns as well. Is there any workaround for this?

Edit:
adding the list output for better reproducibility:

```
{'servers.added': [nan, "['https://api.lnmarkets.com']", nan, "['https://api.testnet.lnmarkets.com']", nan, nan, "['http://mercure.local']", nan, "['https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/VNGRealisatie/api/reisdocumenten']", "['https://www.haalcentraal.nl/haalcentraal/api/brp']"], 'Servers_added': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Comment: can you post a testable fragment of `servers['servers.added'].to_list()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values looks like valid python list, so you can convert these string to real lists. Just replace empty rows by `'[]'` and evaluate with `ast.literal_eval` (or `pd.eval`):

```
import ast

df['count'] = (df['servers.added'].replace(np.nan, '[]')
                  .apply(ast.literal_eval).str.len())
print(df)

# Output
                                        servers.added  count
0                                                           
1                       ['https://api.lnmarkets.com']      1
2                                                          0
3               ['https://api.testnet.lnmarkets.com']      1
4                                                          0
5                                                          0
6                            ['http://mercure.local']      1
7                                                          0
8              ['https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/']      1
9                    ['https://www.haalcentraal.nl/']      1
10                   ['https://api.features4.com/v1']      1
11                    ['https://vwt-d-gew1-dat.com/']      1
12                ['https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/']      1
13                                                         0
14  ['http://localhost:8000/api/v1', 'https://loca...      2
```

Another strategy:

```
df['count'] = (df['servers.added'].str.extract(r'\[([^\]]*)', expand=False)
                   .str.split(',').str.len().fillna(0).astype(int))
print(df)

# Output
                                       servers.added  Servers_added  count
0                                                NaN              1      0
1                      ['https://api.lnmarkets.com']              1      1
2                                                NaN              1      0
3              ['https://api.testnet.lnmarkets.com']              1      1
4                                                NaN              1      0
5                                                NaN              1      0
6                           ['http://mercure.local']              1      1
7                                                NaN              1      0
8  ['https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/VNGRealisa...              1      1
9  ['https://www.haalcentraal.nl/haalcentraal/api...              1      1
```

Comment: This gives me the Value error: `ValueError: malformed node or string: nan`

Comment: I tried this on the entire dataset, and it doesn't work unfortunately, it says this:`ValueError: malformed node or string: ['https://api.lnmarkets.com']`

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative solution. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code look correct but you also count the value the null values as 1, just add a condition to check for null values and return 0 instead of 1

you could do it like that

```
servers.loc[:, 'Servers_added'] = servers['servers.added'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: len([s for s in x.split(',') if s.strip()]) if x.strip() else 0)
```

Comment: This is the same code I posted

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather sorry, this is the code that should fix your problem

Comment: This gives me the same output I am getting, it does not solve the issue